# active directory asp.net forms authentication in asp.net mvc 3

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have to implement an interface like this:

```
interface IMembershipWrapper
{
  Guid GetUserId();
  Guid GetUserId(string username, bool userIsOnline);
  bool ValidateUser(string userName, string password);
    …
}
```

against active directory and inject it using Unity.

I might get away with throwing a NotImplementedException exception for certain methods but do you think it is generally possible? What strategy do you recommend?

I understand that I can configure 'active directory asp.net forms authentication' via the web.config as described [here](http://helios.ca/2009/05/04/aspnet-mvc-forms-authentication-with-active-directory/). Unfortunately, this is not an option.

Comment: Cam you use Windows authentication?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be completely possible without changing your authentication system in the web.config. Especially if you're using .NET 3.5+. Take a look at [System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx).

To implement `GetUserId(string username, bool userIsOnline)` you may want to try something like:

```
public Guid GetUserId(string username, bool userIsOnline) {
    using(PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "[active directory domain here]")) {
        var user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, IdentityType.SamAccountName, username);
        if(user != null)
            return user.Guid.Value;
        else
            return null;
    }
}
```

To implement `ValidateUser(string userName, string password)` use `ValidateCredentials()` on the `PrinicalContext`

```
public bool ValidateUser(string userName, string password) {
    using (PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "[active directory domain here]"))
    {
        return pc.ValidateCredentials(userName, password);
    }
}
```

Without more information about your implementation, I'm not sure how to go about implementing `GetUserId()`, since it seems like you wouldn't have enough information to go to Active Directory with.